# Accessing Session inside Fluent Validation with MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

Is it possible to access the session inside the fluent validation like that:

```
public class MyClassValidator : AbstractValidator<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassValidator()
    {            
        Custom(x =>
        {
            // Need to Get a List that is in the Controller Session 
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not inject your dependency, i.e. the List, into the constructor

Comment: And How can I inject a TempData lista in validator constructor?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're invoking your Validator, but TempData is just a IDictionary<string, object> http://goo.gl/pVvDYV. You can just accept it as a parameter to the contructor